# RPC node is rebooting itself from time to time

Tags: rpc, substrate-node, relay-chain

Node is working correct but there is a moment that shows the following error messages and reboots:

```
2023-10-12 19:39:26 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:26 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:27 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:27 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:27 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:27 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:27 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:27 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:27 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:27 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:28 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:28 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:28 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:28 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:28 Accepting new connection 170/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:28 Accepting new connection 171/10000
2023-10-12 19:39:28 Accepting new connection 171/10000
023-10-12 19:39:28 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="candidate-validation-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "candidate-validation", source: Generated(Context("Signal cha
nnel is terminated and empty.")) }
2023-10-12 19:39:28 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="availability-distribution-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "availability-distribution", source: IncomingMessageChan
nel(Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty."))) }
2023-10-12 19:39:28 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="availability-recovery-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "availability-recovery", source: Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty.")) }
2023-10-12 19:39:28 [Relaychain] error receiving message from subsystem context: Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty.")) err=Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty."))
2023-10-12 19:39:28 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="chain-api-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "chain-api", source: Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty.")) }
2023-10-12 19:39:28 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="bitfield-signing-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "bitfield-signing", source: Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty.")) }
2023-10-12 19:39:28 [Relaychain] Overseer exited with error err=Generated(SubsystemStalled("approval-voting-subsystem"))
2023-10-12 19:39:28 [Relaychain] Essential task `overseer` failed. Shutting down service.    
2023-10-12 19:39:28 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="runtime-api-subsystem" err=Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty."))
2023-10-12 19:39:28 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="statement-distribution-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "statement-distribution", source: SubsystemReceive(Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty."))) }
2023-10-12 19:39:28 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="dispute-distribution-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "dispute-distribution", source: SubsystemReceive(Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty."))) }
2023-10-12 19:39:28 [Relaychain] Failed to receive a message from Overseer, exiting err=Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty."))
Error: 
   0: ESC[91mOther: Essential task failed.ESC[0m

Backtrace omitted.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
2023-10-12 19:40:35 Composable    
2023-10-12 19:40:35 ✌️  version 9.10039.1-77660b43b564c969444f0544df90fdb7cf58b865    
2023-10-12 19:40:35 ❤️  by Composable Developers, 2020-2023    
2023-10-12 19:40:35  Chain specification: Composable Finance    
2023-10-12 19:40:35   Node name: composable-network-rpc-01    
2023-10-12 19:40:35  Role: FULL
```

What can be the cause of this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [following issue](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/1730) it seems that this is still under investigation